# repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra on amazon linux 2 while building and AMI and I am unable install coassandra due to the following error

```
https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: \[Errno 14\] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

\<pre\> \<**==\> amazon-ebs.linux: https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: \[Errno 14\] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux: Trying other mirror.**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:  One of the configured repositories failed (Apache Cassandra),**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:  and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:  safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:      1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:      2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         packages for the previous distribution release still work).**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:      3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:             yum --disablerepo=cassandra ...**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:      4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:             yum-config-manager --disable cassandra**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         or**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:             subscription-manager repos --disable=cassandra**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:      5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:         compromise:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:             yum-config-manager --save --setopt=cassandra.skip_if_unavailable=true**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux:**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from cassandra: \[Errno 256\] No more mirrors to try.**

**==\> amazon-ebs.linux: https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/repodata/repomd.xml: \[Errno 14\] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found**\>
```

Repo config that I am using:

```
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS
```

Step for installing , the same steps worked earlier ,but I am seeing ami build failures recently.

```
 sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y
 sudo mv /tmp/files/cassandra-repo /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra311x.repo
 sudo yum clean all
 sudo yum update -y 
 sudo rpm --import https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS
 sudo yum install cassandra -y
```

Is there anything that recently changed for yum install and the repo data, can you guy's help me how we can fix this issue.

Comment: Its 404 error. Did you checked the baseurl? It doesn't seem to exist. You might need to check and change it accordingly.

Comment: Check this page - and try changing baserepo as - "https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html"  ```baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/```